# Error attribute has already been defined...values.xml and build.gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I know this question have been asked a lot..but I can't resolve this problem.
I have received this message when i try to sync my build.gradle:

.../app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml

```
Error:(1589) Attribute "navigationMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(979) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1596) Attribute "displayOptions" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(690) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1613) Attribute "layout_scrollFlags" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(864) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1215) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1860) Attribute "tabMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(1146) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1863) Attribute "tabGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(1138) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1868) Attribute "passwordToggleTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(1028) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1880) Attribute "buttonGravity" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(562) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(1887) Attribute "backgroundTintMode" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(169) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

This is my build.gradle(app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

I do not understand where I wrong...

Comment: You are defining these attributes twice.